# Why do we use pyspark UDF when python functions are faster than them? (Note. Not worrying about spark SQL commands)

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe:

```
df = (spark
  .range(0, 10 * 1000 * 1000)\
  .withColumn('id', (col('id') / 1000).cast('integer'))\
  .withColumn('v', rand()))
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|                  v|
+---+-------------------+
|  0|0.05011803459635367|
|  0| 0.6749337782428327|
|  0| 0.9449105904567048|
|  0| 0.9183605955607251|
|  0|  0.648596393346793|
+---+-------------------+
```

Now, a simple - Add 1 to 'v' can be done via SQL functions and UDF.

If we ignore the SQL (best performant)

We can create a UDF as:

```
@udf("double")
def plus_one(v):
    return v + 1
```

and call it:

```
df.withColumn('v', plus_one(df.v)).agg(count(col('v'))).show()
```

Time: 16.5sec

But here is my question:

if I **DO NOT** use udf and directly write:

```
def plus_one(v):
        return v + 1
df.withColumn('v', plus_one(df.v)).agg(count(col('v'))).show()
```

Time Taken - 352ms

In a nutshell, the UDF query took ~ 16secs whereas a normal python function took ~ 350ms

To compare,

```
df.selectExpr("id", "v+1 as v").agg(count(col('v'))).show()
```

Time: 347ms

Here is my dilemma:

If I can perform the same scenario with a normal python function that performs comparatively to built-in functions...

Q. Why don't we use a python function directly?

Q. Does registering UDF only matter if we plan to use it inside a SQL like a command?

There must be some optimization reason why we don't do it...or maybe something related to how spark cluster works?

[ There are 2 questions already answered, but both of these ends with "SQL built-in functions are preferred..."
I'm comparing a python function with UDF and it's feasibility in pyspark application. ]

Edit:
I have done this with pandas_udf too:

```
@pandas_udf('double')
def vectorized_plus_one(v):
    return v + 1

df.withColumn('v', vectorized_plus_one(df.v)).agg(count(col('v'))).show()
```

Time: 5.26 secs

I've attached a screenshot:

[The output for Adding 1 to value - Python funtion (standalone), UDF, SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXVwE.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scenario works because actually you don't add 1 in python, it's added in Java in a way very similar to one used when you do it with SQL.

Let's split the case apart:

1. You do `plus_one(df.v)` which is equal to just passing `df.v + 1`
2. Try to type `df.v + 1` in your favorite repl and you'll see that it returns object of type `Column`.
3. How can it be? `Column` class has `__radd__` magic method overwritten(along with some others) and returns new `Column` instance with the instruction to add 1 to the specified column.

In summary: `withColumn` always accepts objects of type `Column` as the second argument and trick with adding 1 to your column is the magic of python.

That's why it works faster than `udf` and `vectorized udf`: they need to run python process, serialize/deserialize data(vectorized udfs can work faster with `arrow` to avoid serializing/deserializing), compute in slower python process.

Comment: So, in a long run, python function, as-is, will surely fail if I chain some complex logic then?

Thank you though, I can understand how just a python function may lead to 'column is not iterable' error.

Comment: Yes it will if you do manipulations that don't return new `Column` object. In general only simple arithmetical operations and functions from `pyspark.sql.functions` can do that. For everything else you need to use udfs.